# Foundation 5.5.1 Layout breaks for grid classes with uneven height

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to have a 2 columns layout where the heights of the div are not fixed. Ideally id use the `small-6` class I should have 2 divs next to each other.

The problem arises if I have more than 2 divs with uneven heights. This causes the layout to break horribly.

Here is an example. Ideally I'd want to have a red bordered and a green bordered div side by side. But since the divs don't have the same height, the layout breaks.

```css
.text {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text:nth-child(2n){
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text">i some text</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```